# How to maintain line breaks in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have an asp.net textbox which has line breaks and the line breaks are not maintained in sql server 2008. How do I do this?

Comment: Employ parameterized queries - anything else is unacceptable from a security POV. This will transparently handle newlines.

Comment: What do you mean by "not maintained" ? have you checked that select CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), YOURCOLUMN) from YOURTABLE returns 0 ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CHAR(13)` for `line breaks` and `CHAR(10)` for `Line Feed (LF)`.

So what you can do is before inserting it into the database, replace each line breaks with `CHAR(13)`.

Here you go:

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(50)
SET @text = 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13) + 'This is line 2.'
SELECT @text
```

Comment: Why is the \r\n getting replaces in sql server table? How can I avoid from getting replaced

Comment: SQL Server has it's own methods and functionality. so it uses `CHAR(10)` for `Line Feed (LF)` and `CHAR(13)` for `Carriage Return (CR)`

Answer (score 3):

```
replace( queryText, '\r\n', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) )
```

Answer (score 2):

All I had to do was this

```
string htmlFormattetText = txtShare.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
```

Comment: I guess you just introduced html markup in your database. Your carriage return were in your DB. All you had to do was replace them with <br/> when displaying text in html format

Comment: I hope you only intend to use this data for web use.

Comment: So you’re saying that the line breaks *were* preserved in T-SQL for you.

Comment: To those reading... The line breaks ARE preserved in T-SQL. There is CSS that does exactly what sly_Chandan posted. It's white-space: pre. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space Feel free to read on this.